# Error: ! Can't combine `..1$exists` <double> and `..350$exists` <character>

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I wrote a code in which loop through a folder with different files which are 2500. The names of the variable found in the list called `flight_info_1` are `path` and `data`. When I want to unnest it, I god following error. Can give me someone a hint?

With kind regards

```
library(prettydoc)

library(tidyverse)
library(fs)
library(purrr)
library(haven)
library(gghalves)
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
library(GGally)
library(vtable)
library(ggridges)
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
library(highcharter)
library(plotly)
library(patchwork)
library(ggdark)
library(ggthemes)
library(rnaturalearth)
`%||%` <- rlang::`%||%`


flight_info_1 <- "Path/Path/" %>%
  dir_ls(recurse = TRUE, type = "file") %>%
  as_tibble_col("path")  %>%
  mutate(data = map(path, function(path_i){
    
    path_i <<- path_i
    
    data_i <- read_csv(path_i, show_col_types=FALSE)
    
    # if(nrow(data_i)==0)
    # {return(NULL)}
    
    
    data_i$date <- as.character(data_i[["date"]] %||% NA_character_)
    
    moved_vars <- tibble(.rows=nrow(data_i))
    
    if(isTRUE(str_detect(data_i[["airline"]] %||% "", "€"))) {
      moved_vars <- bind_cols(moved_vars, select(data_i, price = airline))
    }
    
    
    if(isTRUE(str_detect(data_i[["price"]] %||% "", "hr|min"))){
      moved_vars <- bind_cols(moved_vars, select(data_i, duration = price))
    }
    
    if(isTRUE(str_detect(data_i[["emissions"]] %||% "", "[included]"))){
      moved_vars <- bind_cols(moved_vars, select(data_i, luggage = emissions))
    }



   if(isTRUE(str_detect(data_i[["luggage"]] %||% "", "(?i)kg"))){
      moved_vars <- bind_cols(moved_vars, select(data_i, emissions = luggage))
    }
    
    if(isTRUE(str_detect(data_i[["duration"]] %||% "",  "^[[:alpha:][:space:]]+$"))){
      moved_vars <- bind_cols(moved_vars, select(data_i, airline = duration))
    }
    
    data_i_mod <- bind_cols(
      moved_vars, select(data_i, -any_of(colnames(moved_vars)))
    )
    
    return(data_i_mod)
    
  }))
```

```
data_csv <- unnest(flight_info_1, data)

Error:
! Can't combine `..1$exists` <double> and `..350$exists` <character>.
Backtrace:
  1. tidyr::unnest(flight_info_1, data)
  2. tidyr:::unnest.data.frame(flight_info_1, data)
  3. tidyr::unchop(data, any_of(cols), keep_empty = keep_empty, ptype = ptype)
  4. tidyr:::df_unchop(cols, ptype = ptype, keep_empty = keep_empty)
  5. vctrs::vec_unchop(col, ptype = col_ptype)
  6. vctrs (local) `<fn>`()
  7. vctrs::vec_default_ptype2(...)
  8. vctrs::stop_incompatible_type(...)
  9. vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
 10. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
```

Comment: Transform all the data into one type, ie character

Comment: Hi could you make your example a minimal example by removing all the library calls you don’t need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

```
 data_i_mod <- bind_cols(
      moved_vars, select(data_i, -any_of(colnames(moved_vars)))
    )
    
    data_i_mod <- data_i_mod %>% mutate(across(where(is.double), as.character))
    
    return(data_i_mod)
```